# Norm of a the skew symmetric part of a unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a unitary matrix, $U$ can be nonsymmetric, its eigenvalues can be complex numbers and all have modulus $1$.

Is there an upper bound for the maximum **singular value** of its skew symmetric part (which is not necessarily unitary) depending on its eigenvalues?

i.e.: Is there an $f$ such that
$\left\|\frac{U - U^T}{2} \right\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}\left(\frac{U - U^T}{2}\right) \le  f\left(\lambda_i\left(U\right)\right)$ ?

More details:

Observe that if $U=I$ (eigenvalues are real) $\Rightarrow \left\|\frac{U - U^T}{2} \right\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}\left(\frac{U - U^T}{2}\right) = 0$, and if $U$ is skew-symmetric (eigenvalues purely imaginary) $\Rightarrow\left\|\frac{U - U^T}{2} \right\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}\left(\frac{U - U^T}{2}\right) = 1$. Therefore there is a relationship between the norm $\left\|\frac{U - U^T}{2} \right\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}\left(\frac{U - U^T}{2}\right)$ and the argument of the eigenvalues of $U$, i.e. $f\left(\lambda_i\left(U\right)\right) = f\left(\text{arg}(\lambda_i\left(U\right))\right)$.

Further notes: in my work $U$ is the unitary factor of the polar decomposition of an M-matrix, but this may be irrelevant.

Comment: Remark: in my corner of functional analysis, $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ would normally denote $\ell^2$-norm (i.e. Hilbert-Schmidt norm, a.k.a. Frobenius norm). I'm guessing from context you mean the $\ell^2$-to-$\ell^2$ norm?

Comment: Also, one is getting trivial bounds if your function $f$ is "absolute value". So perhaps you should be more precise about what kinds of dependence on the eigenvalues you are after

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks for your interest! I am referring to the spectral norm of the matrix; i.e. its maximum singular value. If $f$ is the absolute value, meaning the modulus of a complex number, then it is equal to 1 given that all the eigenvalues of unitary matrices lie in the unit circle of the complex plane. I am looking for a relationship between the maximum **singular value** of the **skew-symmetric part** of $U$ (which is not necessarily unitary) and eigenvalues of $U$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The spectral radius of $U$ is the maximum eigenvalue which clearly has modulus 1 but I am interested in the maximum **singular value** of the **skew-symmetric part** of $U$, which is not necessarily unitary.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks again. Your statement is correct, all skew symmetric parts of $U$ have operator norm and spectral radius at most $1$, also, all unitary matrices have operator norm and spectral radius at most $1$. I guess you can see that the operator norm of the skew-symmetric part can be smaller (even zero)? How does that depend on the eigenvalues of $U$?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks again! I am very interested now, can you cook up one of those examples of a unitary $U$ whose skew-symmetric part has spectral radius $2$? I don't think it exists...

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks a lot!! I think we're getting somewhere. The example you give has pure imaginary eigenvalues. That is exactly my point, look, when the eigenvalues of $U$ are purely imaginary, the spectral radius of the skew-symmetric part is $1$, when they are purely real, the spectral radius of the skew-symmetric part is $0$. The question is: what happens with the maximum **singular value** in the middle, when the arguments are neither $n \pi$ nor $\frac{(2n+1) \pi }{2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Is there an upper bound for it, less than $1$, depending on the spectrum of $U$?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Bare with me please, I don't understand. The diagonalization $V$ would not belong to $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I am talking about unitary matrices over the fields of real numbers.

Comment: Unitary real matrices are usually called orthogonal matrices. I was thinking about complex matrices and had not noticed that you were only looking at real ones.

Comment: In the case that $U$ is a real orthogonal matrix, any eigenvector ( possibly complex) of $U$ with egenvalue $\alpha$ is also an eigenvalue of $U^{T}$ with eigenvalue ${\bar \alpha},$ and it easily follows that the eigenvalues of  the skew symmetric part of $U$ are precisely the imaginary parts of the eigenvalues of $U$. Hence the spectral radius of the skew-symmetric part of $U$ is the maximum of the absolute value of the imaginary parts of the eigenvalues of $U.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I cannot thank you enough for the explanation. Now the question was: is there an upper bound for the singular values of the skew-symmetric part? (aside from $1$).

Comment: See my answer below. I don't think there is anything more to say beyond that.

Comment: @Astor One reason for my confusion is that there is a trivial upper bound for $\sigma_{\max}$ of the skew-symmetric part, namely $1$. Your question asked for a function of the eigenvalues that provides an upper bound. My function is $f(z)=1$. If my function is not good enough for your purposes, please explain why.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thank you. I gladly explain. Take any matrix with purely real eigenvalues (e.g. Identity), the maximum singular value of its skew-symmetric part is $0$. If we were to consider the trivial upper bound $1$ we would be overestimating it extremely. The upper bound is attained, for instance, when the eigenvalues are purely imaginary. All this points to a dependency between the maximum singular value of the skew-symmetric part and the arguments of the eigenvalues of $U$. This is the relationship I am seeking.

Comment: I would also like to observe that since $U-U^\top$ is $i$ times a complex Hermitian matrix, its eigenvalues all lie on the imaginary axis, and its spectral radius is equal to its operator norm.

Comment: By the way, the title is a bit misleading. You want the norm of the skew-symmetric part of $U,$ and the skew-symmetric part of $U$ is not necessarily unitary itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I misread the question I will clarify my comments into a formal answer (which is, in the end, quite elementary). Since $U$ is a real orthogonal matrix,
it has a basis of eigenvectors when viewed as a complex matrix say $\{v_{1},v_{2}, \ldots,v_{n} \}.$ Also, the eigenvalues of $U$ all lie on the unit circle, and the non-real ones occur in complex conjugate pairs.

Whenever $v$ is an eigenvector of $U$ with eigenvalue $\alpha,$ it is also an eigenvector of $U^{T}$ with eigenvalue ${\bar \alpha}.$ Hence if $v_{j}$ is an eigenvector of $U$ with eigenvector $\alpha_{j},$ then $v_{j}$ is an eigenvector of $\frac{U-U^{T}}{2}$ with eigenvalue $i{\rm Im}(\alpha_{j}).$ Hence the spectral radius of $\frac{U-U^{T}}{2}$ is the maximum element of $\{ |{\rm Im}(\alpha_{j})| : 1 \leq j \leq n \}.$ This can only be $0$ when all eigenvalues of $U$ are $\pm 1,$ and can only be $1$ if $U$ has $i$ as an eigenvalue.

If you prefer, you can write $\alpha_{j} = \exp(i \beta_{j})$ with $0 \leq \beta_{j} < 2 \pi$ and then $\frac{U-U^{T}}{2}$ has spectral radius
the maximum element of  $\{ |\sin(\beta_{j})|: 1 \leq j \leq n \}$
and $\frac{U - U^{T}}{2}$ has eigenvalues $\{ i\sin(\beta_{j}) : 1 \leq j \leq n \}$ ( even allowing for multiplicities, by a slight abuse of notation).

Since a real skew-symmetric matrix is certainly normal (ie commutes with its transpose), the largest of the absolute values of its eigenvalues is its largest singular value (which is also its operator norm with respect to the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}).$ Hence this is the maximum element of  $\{ |\sin(\beta_{j})|: 1 \leq j \leq n \}.$

Comment: By studying the spectral radius, you are finding the elementary **lower** bound for the maximum singular value of the skew-symmetric part.
The whole point of the question is to find an **upper** bound for the maximum singular value of the skew-symmetric part.

Comment: @Astor The spectral radius is the same as the largest singular value, so I don't understand your comment. Furthermore, both Geoff and I are fully aware of the difference between orthogonal matrices, unitary matrices, and (skew-)symmetric matrices

Comment: I have explicitly given ALL eigenvalues of the skew symmetric part of $U,$ expressed in terms of the eigenvalues of $U$. What else do you want to know?

Comment: @YemonChoi  It is very likely that I am the ignorant here and if it is the case I apologize. The spectral radius of a matrix is the largest **eigenvalue modulus**, not the largest **singular value**. Is there a proof that for all unitary matrices the maximum modulus of its eigenvalues is equal to the maximum singular value?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks for your patience. I'd like to know the maximum singular value of the skew-symmetric part of $U$, not its eigenvalues. Unless of course you could provide a bijection between them?

Comment: @Astor see my comment to your original question. Both Geoff and I assumed that you knew that the largest singular value of a skew symmetric real matrix is equal to its spectral radius.

Comment: It is standard theory that if a real matrix is diagonalizable via a unitary matrix, then its largest singular value is the largest absolute value of its eigenvalues. Any normal matrix may be diagonalized by a unitary matrix. A real matrix $A$ is normal if $A$ commutes with $A^{T}.$ Clearly, any symmetric, any skew-symmetric, and any orthogonal real matrix, is normal. Hence the largest singular value of a real skew-symmetric matrix ( which is also its operator norm), is the largest of teh absolute values of its eigenvalues.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Million thanks. I have understood. I'm sorry it took so long. Could you put this last comment as the first paragraph of your answer? Then I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I have put that part of the explanation at the end of the proof.

Comment: For a general complex unitary matrix $U$, the right thing to do is to look at the skew-Hermitian part of $U,$ and then a very similar argument works to yield a similar conclusion.